# Julia, parsimonious way to create Int8 array of 3's?

Tags: arrays, integer, julia

Seems simple but I can't figure it out.  What is the simplest way in Julia to create a new array of type Int8, containing ten 3's ?  Thx. J

Obviously

```
Int8[3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]
```

works but I want to produce much larger arrays.

Comment: `fill(Int8(3), 8, 33)`

Comment: Just always remember not to use as `fill` arguments references to complex types (such as `mutable struct` or `Array`)

Answer (score 2):

@mcabbott's suggestion

```
fill(Int8(3), 10)
```

was my first thought and the best choice IMHO, but you can also do one of these if your preference goes to any of them

```
[Int8(3) for _ in 1:10]
```

or

```
Int8.(3 * ones(10))
```

or

```
Int8(3) * ones(Int8, 10)
```

[**EDIT**] or (Oscar Smith suggestion)

```
Int8(3) .+ zeros(Int8, 10)
```

Comment: For big values of `10`, `Int8(3) .+ zeros(Int8, 10)` is likely to be faster since the OS often gives zeroed memory on allocation.

Comment: @OscarSmith does it? I thought this is not the case, which is why `malloc` and `calloc` are different functions. But I know little about C.